How to import Tailwind types now that `tailwindcss/tailwind-config` doesn't exist?
I am trying to update some old code. I used to import Tailwind types like
import { TailwindColorConfig, TailwindColorGroup } from 'tailwindcss/tailwind-config'

But now
Cannot find module 'tailwindcss/tailwind-config' or its corresponding type declarations.ts    

This is the file
import resolveConfig from 'tailwindcss/resolveConfig'
import { TailwindColorConfig, TailwindColorGroup } from 'tailwindcss/tailwind-config'
import tailwindConfig from '../../tailwind.config'

export interface ThemeColorConfig extends TailwindColorConfig {
  primary: TailwindColorGroup
}

export const useThemeColors = (): ThemeColorConfig => {
  const twConfig = resolveConfig(tailwindConfig)
  if (!twConfig?.theme?.colors) throw new Error('Missing Tailwind config')
  return twConfig.theme.colors as ThemeColorConfig
}

How to import Tailwind types now that tailwindcss/tailwind-config doesn't exist?
